# Unclear when to use firebase client sdk and firebase admin sdk

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm diving into a web app project for a job site where users can sign up and apply for job openings posted by different organizations. I'm thinking of using Firebase and Node.js for the server backend.

I'm kind of stuck on when to use Firebase Client SDK and when to switch to Admin SDK. If anyone has some insight on how these SDKs play along with a Node.js backend, I'd really appreciate your thoughts.

Also, if there are any alternative suggestions or things you think would work better, I'm all ears.

Thanks a bunch in advance for any advice or experiences you can share.

Comment: For additional conxtext, i am using html,css and vue js to develop my frontend

Answer (score 2):

> I'm kinda of stuck on when to use Firebase Client SDK and when to switch to Admin SDK.

As the name says, you should use the Firebase Client SDK for the web, on the client. This means that you can attach a listener and you can stay in sync with the Firebase servers. So each time something on the server changes, you're notified in real-time. Since you interact with the data client side, you can also set security rules to allow some operations only for the users that are allowed to do them.

On the other hand, you can use the Admin SDK to do operations from a trusted environment, meaning that all operations will bypass the security rules entirely. To understand better, you can create a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) that will fire each time a user [authenticates to Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation). This means that once a user is authenticated you can write the details of the authentication in [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) for example. This operation of writing the data is performed using the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup). Remember that all operations are performed with full admin privileges.

Comment: He Sam. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?